# Сама задается переменная PHP

Tags: php, php.ini

Я тут пишу в отдельном файле код для работы с ini и отдельно все работает. Когда я положил в свой проект, то почему-то переменная $ini в функции Open null, а в AddSection уже такая:

```
object(WriteIni)#2 (2) {
    ["Path":"WriteIni":private]=>
    NULL
    ["File":"WriteIni":private]=>
    NULL
}

object(WriteIni)#2 (2) {
    ["Path":"WriteIni":private]=>
    NULL
    ["File":"WriteIni":private]=>
    NULL
}
```

Почему так выходит?
Вот весь код в файле с ошибкой:

```
                <?php
                class WriteIni {

                    private $Path;
                    private $File;

                    public function Open($path)
                    {
                        global $Path, $ini;
                        $Path = $path;
                    }
                    public function AddSection($section)
                    {
                        echo "<pre>";
                        var_dump($GLOBALS["ini"]);
                        echo "</pre>";
                        global $ini;
                        echo "<pre>";
                        var_dump($GLOBALS["ini"]);
                        echo "</pre>";
                        if (!isset($ini))
                        {
                            $this->GetIni();
                        }
                        if (!isset($ini[$section]))
                        {
                            $ini[$section] = array();
                        }
                    }
                    public function AddVar($section, $name, $value)
                    {
                        global $Path, $ini;
                        if (!isset($ini))
                        {
                            $ini = $this->GetIni();
                        }

                        $ini[$section][$name] = $value;
                        //$this->Write_Create($ini);
                    }

                    public function Save()
                    {
                        $this->Write_Create($GLOBALS["ini"]);
                    }
                    public function Close()
                    {
                        $GLOBALS["Path"] = null;
                        $GLOBALS["ini"] = null;
                    }


                    function GetIni()
                    {
                        global $Path, $ini;
                        if (file_exists($Path))
                        {
                            $ini = parse_ini_file($Path, true);
                            if (!isset($ini)) {
                                $ini = array();
                            }
                            unlink($Path);
                        }
                        else {
                            $ini = array();
                        }
                    }
                    function Write_Create($ini)
                    {
                        global $Path;
                        $File = fopen($Path, "w");
                        foreach ($ini as $key => $section)
                        {
                            fwrite($File, "['".$key."']\n");
                        
                            foreach ($section as $vkey => $value)
                            {
                                fwrite($File, "\t'".$vkey."'='".$value."';\n");
                            }
                        }
                        fclose($File);
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Подключается и используется он в другом файле так:

```
require_once "../../ReactData/ReactPHP/ini.php";
    $ini = new WriteIni();
    $ini->Open("../../protected/react-config.ini");

    $ini->AddSection("Server");
    $ini->AddVar("Server", "Host", $host);
    $ini->AddVar("Server", "User", $name);
    $ini->AddVar("Server", "Password", $pasw);
    $ini->AddVar("Server", "DB", $db);
    $ini->AddVar("Server", "Prefix", $prefix);
    
    $ini->Save();
    $ini->Close();
```

Comment: global $ini; - явно где-то ещё изменяется, не стоит использовать global

Comment: А что тогда можно использовать вместо него?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался по 1 комментарию, я подумал, и посмотрел, что переменная внутри вызывающего файла такая же как и в файле с классом - $ini. Подтвердилось это тем что когда я изменил название - все заработало. Далее в классе я заменил все переменные $ini с global на $this->ini, что бы оно принадлежало исключительно экземпляру класса. После этого все заработало.